# Where can I find a simple barrister bookcase door mechanism, or how can I make one?

Tags: self-assembly-furniture

I have two old Sauder Barrister bookcases- they were inexpensive but are still useful. Four of the plastic catch parts from the hanging door mechanisms have broken. I would like to purchase replacement parts, but don’t know where to find them; or I would consider making them myself if I knew how. Information about this appreciated very much. Thank you
[image]

Above, this is a picture of one unbroken door catch part that I need.
[image]

The door catch parts hang and slide on this second part of the simple barrister bookcase mechanism.

Comment: Many woodworkers' supply houses sell mechanisms and plans for barristers' bookcases. There are also plans which feature homebrew versions of the mechanism, available from those same stores and/or from woodworking magazine articles. Unfortunately, "shopping questions" (where can I buy...) are out of bounds here.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find one for sale, this seems to be *exactly* what 3D printing was invented for.

If you've got a friend/coworker/neighbor who has a 3D printer, ask if they'd be willing to help you make one. Offer to pay for time & materials, or possibly just a 6-pack of their favorite beverage.

If not, there are services in many larger cities that will do a 3D scan of the item which generates the measured drawing that is then fed into the printer. They will, of course, charge you more, but you'd have the part you were after and if you can't find one for sale, this might be the only option.

---

A simple "make-do" solution would be to drive a short screw into the door panel to act as the catch. It wouldn't be as pretty, and you'd have to take care to ensure that you get the screw centered properly on the stop pin *and* be sure to not drive it through the other side of the door, but it would do the trick.

Instead of a bare screw, you might try something like a "screw on rubber bumper", like this:

[image: poor image of a set of rubber bumpers]
<sup>Image courtesy of Amazon.com.
No recommendation implied or intended, it was the second search result and the first one I could get an image to from.</sup>

Put it on the inside of the door in place of the specifically designed bracket. Again, make sure you line it up (these are much wider, so you've got more leeway), and be *sure* not to drill all the way through the door.